# How to use functional interface (perhaps) to pass comparison operator to a while loop?

Tags: java, code-duplication, functional-interface

I have two almost identical methods, the only difference is than one goes "left" and the second "right" from the spot in the array.

Is there any way how to de-duplicate these tow methods?

Using Functional Interface & function perhaps?

```
void goLeft(int number, int index, int increment, int to) {
  int localMax = 0;
  int i = index;
  while (i > to) {
    i += increment; // passed increment is negative
    // common body
  }
}

void goRight(int number, int index, int increment, int to) {
  int localMax = 0;
  int i = index;
  while (i < to) {
    i += increment; // passed increment is positive
    // common body
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to *pass it*, you can *create* predicate which will compare `i` with `to` in a way depending on sign of `increment`. Something like `IntPredicate predicate = i>=0 ? (x)-> x<to : (x) -> x>to;` (assuming that `to` is final or at least effectively-final). Now all you need is use `while(predicate.test(i))` instead of your conditions.

Comment: That many primitive-type function parameters, with generic, non-descriptive names, look like a design smell. What's worse, the functions seem to assume the caller knows their insides judging from those comments. Before going into refactoring implementation details, I'd look into refactoring the function contracts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator if the only difference is the condition of the while loop:

```
while (increment < 0 ? i > to : i < to) {
    i += increment; 
    // common body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I did something similar using an enum,
in your case it might be like this:

```
public class Example {
  void go(Direction direction, int number, int index, int to) {
    while (LEFT == direction ? i > to : i < to) {
      i = direction.increment(i);
      // ...
      i = direction.decrement(i);
      // ...
      i = direction.floor(i, to);
      // ...
      var fromIndex = direction.fromIndex(index);
    }
  }
}

public enum Direction {
  LEFT(" <- left") {
    @Override
    int increment(int value) {
      return --value;
    }

    @Override
    int decrement(int value) {
      return ++value;
    }

    @Override
    int floor(int value, int limit) {
      return Math.max(value, limit);
    }

    @Override
    int fromIndex(int value) {
      return value;
    }
  },
  
  RIGHT(" right ->") {
    @Override
    int increment(int value) {
      return ++value;
    }

    @Override
    int decrement(int value) {
      return --value;
    }

    @Override
    int floor(int value, int limit) {
      return Math.min(value, limit);
    }

    @Override
    int fromIndex(int value) {
      return value + 1;
    }
  },
  ;

  final String sign;

  Direction(String sign) {
    this.sign = sign;
  }

  abstract int increment(int value);

  abstract int decrement(int value);

  abstract int floor(int value, int limit);

  abstract int fromIndex(int value);

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return sign;
  }
}
```